# Cannot build Phonegap project from command line

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, phonegap-build

I have built a Phonegap app and am now trying to integrate it with Phonegap Build. I'm following the very simple guide [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface).

So I am doing:

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
sudo phonegap create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd hello

sudo phonegap local build android
```

The last command results in the error:

```
The command `android` failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the `android` command (inside the tools/ folder) added to your path. Output: /bin/sh: 1: android: not found
```

I then did:

```
which android
```

with the result:

```
/home/mark/Development/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/sdk/tools/android
```

which is the corrent path.

The phonegap version is 3.1.0-0.15.0.

Any ideas why I am getting this error?

**Edit**
If I run:

```
sudo phonegap local build /home/mark/Development/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/sdk/tools/android
```

I get yet another error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/local.build.js:141
    platformPath = path.join('.', 'platforms', platform.local);
                                                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined
at LocalBuildCommand.module.exports.addPlatform (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/local.build.js:141:60)
at LocalBuildCommand.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/local.build.js:95:32)
at LocalBuildCommand.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/local.build.js:70:10)
at Object.build (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/util/command.js:28:25)
at CLI.module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/cli/local.build.js:34:20)
at CLI.module.exports [as argv] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/cli/argv.js:66:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/bin/phonegap.js:24:21)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
```

Comment: What you get when you enter "android" in the command line?

Comment: it brings up the android sdk manager...

Comment: is Ant installed and configured?

Comment: I just ran ant -v and it says "Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 3 2011
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed"

Comment: so yes, ant works fine too. any ideas?

Comment: Is build tools installted in the android sdk manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install the phonegap npm global package with sudo, it's ok.
But then you should run phonegap with your own user

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
phonegap create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
phonegap local build android
```

executing with sudo you are switching to root user therefore environment variables as $PATH are not necessarily the same.

Answer (score 1):

Laters version of android sdk moved adb to platform-tools. Try to include both tools and platform-tools in your path. see

> ~/Tools/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk $ cat tools/adb_has_moved.txt
>   The adb tool has moved to platform-tools/
>
> If you don't see this directory in your SDK, launch the SDK and AVD
>   Manager (execute the android tool) and install "Android SDK
>   Platform-tools"
>
> Please also update your PATH environment variable to include the
>   platform-tools/ directory, so you can execute adb from any location.

I use following export commands.

```
export ANDROID_BUNDLE_HOME="$ATILLA_TOOLS/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030"
export ANDROID_SDK_HOME="$ANDROID_BUNDLE_HOME/sdk"
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/platform-tools
```

both adb and android should work in command line. Also try to use

```
phonegap local build android
```

without sudo.

see following example

```
 $phonegap create deneme1 
[phonegap] created project at /home/atilla/Projects/Denemeler/a/deneme1 
 $cd deneme1/ 
 $phonegap local build android
[phonegap] adding the Android platform... 
[phonegap] compiling
Android... [phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
```

After this successful message try to find your platform and apk file.

```
 $ls -al platforms/ 
 $ls -al platforms/android/ 
 $ls -al platforms/android/bin
```

you should see HelloWorld-debug.apk in this directory.

> -rw-r--r--  1 atilla atilla 1542462 Ara  5 14:31 HelloWorld-debug.apk

Answer (score 0):

Try to Add your Android Path to your PATH Enviroment Variables.

if you use Linux, first try:

```
echo $PATH
```

This command display your PATH variable, search the Android path on this.
If you don't see the android path, you need to add that path on your enviroment variable.
Try this:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/mis_prog' >> /home/user/.bashrc
```

You must edit the configuration file of your login shell.
As usually the BASH shell is the most used, you must edit your /home/user/.bashrc.

For this you will use a text editor or just a command to make the task easier.

If you use some Windows Version, you can edith the enviroment variable PATH from system propertyes, something like this: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: the android path has already been to the PATH. When i run just "android" from anywhere, it opens up the SDK manager..